# KeyEvent in android

Tags: android, keyevent

I want to know how to use the onKeyDown event in android.

Because I want to make an app, that Whenever I type in anything in an editText, the Textview will automatically update and display the text i inputted.

Answer (score 1):

I would insist that in your case the better option is to use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for EditText. You can just set the listener for EditText using [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and append the text from EditText to TextView. [Here](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-edittext-textwatcher-example.html) is how you can use TextWatcher for EditText.

Answer (score 0):

this is the method

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Your stuff
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

you can check there for the keyCode or the KeyEvent.

In a project I developed before, I use a runnable method to check the Edittext.